# Nodejs module working only in some folders

Tags: node.js, module, request

It's weird I have a little request (in nodejs) ( `request_working.js` ) that require  the [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request)
The problem is that it works only in some folder because otherwise the module is not found!
For example my folders are this way :
/home/lol/Desktop/**nodejs**/ **newProject**/newProject/node_modules

---

So `node request_working.js` work in the bold folders (working in the nodejs and newProject folder but not in the other newProject folder or in node_modules folder)
Because I have this error :

```
    node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'post'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lol/Desktop/nodejs/newProject/newProject/request_working.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Like if I didn't have request module. (I am using a POST method from the request module)
I am using Express.js ( the newProject folder = Express project ) so I want to put my request_working.js in

```
/home/lol/Desktop/nodejs/newProject/newProject/node_modules
```

to use it as a module.
But how wan I fix this error first ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Are there any other ``node_modules`` directories at any other level of the directory hierarchy? That is, does: ``/home/lol/Desktop/nodejs/node_modules/`` or ``/home/lol/Desktop/nodejs/newProject/node_modules/`` exist?

Comment: paths: [ '/home/lol/repl/node_modules', '/home/lol/node_modules', '/home/node_modules', '/node_modules' ] } THis the path of all node_modules (And yes in /home (and /home/lol) there is one)

Comment: My guess is that you have another instance of whatever you're ``require``ing in ``/home/lol/Desktop/nodejs/newProject/newProject/node_modules/`` that's different from the one in one of the higher-level directories. Try deleting the that directory (the ``node_modules`` deepest in the hierarchy). As far as your other question, you probably want to read up on how to write an NPM package (even if you don't publish it ``"public": false``) so it's easier to re-use your own code in various projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks david, it's working !

How to fix this error ? :
in console type :
`node`
then
`module`
It should gives you all the node_modules folders, 
for example:
`home/lol/newproject/node_modules`
then go in the folder `newproject` if it does not already existcreate a new folder `node_modules`, put you modules in this folder and delete every `node_modules` deeper in the directory example you should delete:
`home/lol/newproject/newproject/node_modules`

THanks again !